# How to stream data from Azure SQL to Azure Blob/Event Hubs?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have a random integer program in python which is posting the random integers into an Azure SQL Database The data in the Azure SQL Database is updating in realtime, and I want to stream this data into Stream Analytics. Unfortunately, this data can only stream every 1 minute which is way to slow. Thus, I am thinking of using a streaming input in Stream Analytics, such as Azure Blob Storage or Event Hubs. Does anyone know how I could transfer and stream my realtime data to one of these 2 sources, so that I could have Stream Analytics collect my random integer data.

I am using Azure SQL Database to store the data in tables, and then using Stream Analytics to serve as a streaming dataset for Power Bi Online.

All services I have mentioned (apart from Power BI) are located in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Why did you use sql server as the first step? I would have python write to stream analytics and have to SA job output to SQL server for storage and power bi for the real time part. Otherwise you will have to poll SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Logic App for that. They have SQL triggers: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/

From there you can easily put a message into Event Hubs or Blob.

Comment: Logic apps have SQL triggers, but that is for SQL databases only not Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: This documentation says otherwise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure